# ngModelCtrl - $setViewValue without $setDirty();

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a directive which manipulates the $viewValue of an input field via ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue() on blur.

```
function _onFocus () {
    presentation = false;
    if(!ctrl.$isEmpty(ctrl.$modelValue)) {
      ctrl.$setViewValue(String(ctrl.$modelValue).replace(/\./, ','));
      ctrl.$render();
    }
  }
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nlmkUnkNjqU7SrP5eIeo?p=preview)

Since this is only an appearance thing, I wonder if there is the possibility of setting the ViewValue without altering the $pristine/$dirty state of the input field itself.

Reference Angular: [$setDirty on $commitViewValue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L662)

Comment: Have you tried ctrl.$setPristine() right after your $render?
Check out your modified [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/touuTeoKhteRbgm7KW0g?p=preview)

Comment: @mengstrom yes and as you can see in your modified plunkr, the $dirty flag will still be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably set the `value` of the element instead of setting view value and rending all over, since it is just the appearance thing that happens on manually registered event, and you do not have to play with the ngmodel's validation properties.

i.e:

```
  function _onBlur () {
     //....
      $element.val(_formatCurrency(ctrl.$modelValue));
  }

  function _onFocus () {
     //...
     $element.val(String(ctrl.$modelValue).replace(/\./, ','));
  }
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/41cK4Q?p=preview)**